# where and when to use &nbsp and &nbsp; this in jsp or html?

Tags: html, jsp

Why to use this in the code while coding?

Where to use this? why the code need this?

Referring to which context we should write this?

How to display text exactly in the center, with equal distance from all the sides?

Comment: This is like asking where and when to use a blue cloth. Can you please be more specific? (To center text you normally use CSS, unless you want a 1995 look and feel.)

Comment: Your final question is should be a seperate one. Also I think it may be already answred.

Answer (score 1):

This code is used to apply a space within your code, you may have noticed when writing HTML, if you leave a massive pile of spaces between two words, the browser ignores it, and therefore thats when

```
&nbsp;
```

is needed.

If you want to center text, there is a number of ways you can do this, the best way is probably to use the CSS rule:

```
text-align: center;
```

See this for more info:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp

Answer (score 1):

`&nbsp;` is an HTML entity encoding a non-breaking space. If you separate two words with `&nbsp;`, web browsers will not split the words over two lines.

`&nbsp` is almost always a typo.

People frequently use `&nbsp;` with normal spaces to add extra horizontal whitespace.

There are other posts covering how to centre text vertically and horizontally - see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vertically+horizontally+centered+text for a range of answers.

Answer (score 0):

`&nbsp;` is a [html ascii character](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm). It represents a space.

When you add multiple spaces after each other in html they will be truncated and only one will be displayed in the rendered page. when you use `&nbsp;` all spaces are rendered on the page.

Comment: BTW, `&nbsp;` is an HTML entity that encodes [a character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) that, as far as I know, does not exist in ASCII.